# Proper way to return private object in Python

Tags: python, class, properties

I'm new to Python (and liking it so far) but have many years experience with OO languages like C++ and C# and consider myself a strong OO designer.

My understanding is that Python does not strictly enforce private object properties, but that by convention people expect that if you name a property with an underscore that they will know not to access it outside the class. OK, fair enough.

My question: if an object contains "private" object and I return it to a caller, should I make a copy so they can't mess it up? Or does Python automatically make a copy?

```
# My Channel class has a dictionary of capabilities  
class Channel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._capabilities = dict()
```

If I do the following can the caller mess with my capabilities by messing with the returned dictionary?

```
@property
def capabilities(self):
    return self._capabilities
```

Or should I do this and return a copy to protect myself?

```
@property
def capabilities(self):
    # I'm assuming that this creates a new copy of the dictionary
    return dict(self._capabilities)
```

I am guessing that Python returns a reference so that the caller can indeed mess with my private dictionary (or list, or whatever) so I better make a copy first.

Comment: You can use `@capabilities.getter` to specify a getter function. What you can do is raise an Exception in that method, so people know better than to try and read it.

Comment: It depends, entirely. This is semantic. If you need them to be able to modify the object, then return a copy. Python uses references for all mutable objects, so it will return what is effectively analogous to a shared_ptr in C++ (Py_IncrRef will be called, even on None).

Generally, `_method` means the type is "protected", it's considered internal and implementation-dependent, but not strictly enforced. A `__method` means any caller outside the immediate class has name mangling, so it's most analogous to "private". These are guidelines.

Comment: "Or does Python automatically make a copy?" - unlike C++, Python almost never makes implicit copies.

Comment: If the internal state depends on the integrity of that object, but it should be "read-only", you might want a getter with no setter that returns a copy. If you are worried about implementation details (say, setting a value updates a database record that is implementation-dependent), you might want to return the existing object without any copies, but still suggest others not to touch the implementation using a `_method`.

Comment: You are right, Python doesn't return a copy. You can check this by printing id(self._capabilities) and the id of the object property.

Comment: Python passes everything by reference (not really, but to use C# lingo...), but some structures are mutable and some are not. There is no need for you to make copies for non-mutable structures as nothing from the outside can change the state of what your internal properties point to. However, for mutable structures you'll need to create copies (or even deep copies) if you expect users of your classes will be modifying them.

Comment: You may want to consider using some sort of proxy object instead of a copy, especially for dicts, where [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType) is available.

Comment: If you're exposing the object (by returning it from a `property`), is it really "private"? If the user shouldn't need to manipulate the dictionary at all (just pass it back to some method, perhaps), you should document the property as returning an opaque object, which just happens to be a dictionary as an implementation detail. It would then be a logic error in the user's code if they mutate the dictionary's contents in a way you don't expect, just like if they access your private `_capabilities` attribute to manipulate it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.3 and above, there is a class in the standard library `types.MappingProxyType`.  Its constructor takes a dictionary and returns a read-only view.  If you return this kind of object, as opposed to a copy of the dictionary, the returned MappingProxyType would raise an exception if client code tried to alter it.

You can also make your class emulate an immutable mapping by inheriting from `collections.abc.Mapping` and implementing three special methods: `__getitem__, __iter__, and __len__`.  Then client code could access any item in `_capabilities` but could not modify it.  A client could even iterate over the whole set.

But Python philosophy ("we're all adults here") says that perhaps it is better to return the dictionary and trust the user's code not to mess with it.  Trying to get Python to emulate C++ is not necessarily the best approach.  As you point out, Python doesn't actually prevent the client from using variables that begin with an underscore.

Comment: "trust the user's code not to mess with it" - I would think of this more as a considerate gesture towards the user, requiring something of a formal process to change global state. I think of it a little like django's handling of the settings.py file - you can read the settings all day long, but it's not for writing, because wow the mess you could make that way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I like Paul's MappintProxyType approach best. A large part of my question was really about Python philosophy. I have seen many developers switch to a new language and try to do things the way you do them with the other language. It is pretty ugly. I'm trying not to be that guy and get into the Python mindset.

Answer (score 0):

I slept on it and realized I could just write a test and figure out my own answer. When I return an object (a dictionary in my test) then I get a reference to the actual private object. If I add an entry to what gets returned then it adds an entry to the original object's dictionary.

So if I want to protect against that then I need to create a copy and return.

```
    @property
    def capabilities(self):
        # I'm assuming that this creates a new copy of the dictionary
        return dict(self._capabilities)
```

I think part of my original question was whether this approach was the common pattern for Python. It is in C# and I intend to do this as a general practice.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may need a deep copy (instead of shallow copy) to be fully protected.

Comment: It's not a common pattern for Python because, usually, we expect users of our code to be adults and not to make changes where they shouldn't. Most of the time it's enough to just denote it in your documentation, i.e. _treat as read-only, if you need to modify this structure make a copy_. Python is slow as it is, we don't want to waste cycles trying to keep users away from harming themselves. After all, you can just make it harder for them, but if they really want to mess with the inner structure of your code there's nothing stopping them, so why bother in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, attributes starting with one underscore are considered private. You can access or modify them but you shouldn't.

However when you create a public attribute you essentially give the user the permission that it's okay to modify what it returns. Python always returns references, the question is just if the reference is mutable or immutable, dictionaries and lists are mutable so they could change the contents, while other types like numbers and strings are immutable so they are "safe to return".

Instead of thinking about how to return a copy you should think about which "properties" and "methods" of `_capabilities` are of interest for a user. For example if you just want a "has_capability" and "value_of_capability" you could simply create functions for that:

```
class Channel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._capabilities = dict()

    def has_capability(self, capability):
        return capability in self._capabilities

    def value_of_capability(self, capability):
        return self._capabilities[capability]
```

and likewise for other operations that should be supported. It doesn't make sense to hide an attribute and then to "expose" it (no matter if as reference or as copy). The problem with a copy is that it is slow and it's likely to lead to surprises because you can modify it but the changes don't propagate back. That's not really intuitive.